# Swift Version of ObjectiveC macro

Tags: objective-c, swift

I used Below code in ObjectiveC and worked but in swift giving error.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Help me to get its Swift version.

Comment: Swift does not support macro like in Objective-C. You can replace them by a variable 'let' like in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative in Swift:

```
let isPad = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let isPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad
```

Comment: got error - use of unresolved identifier UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM

Comment: Note that `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is commented as to be used only if you deploy for very old versions of iOS. You might want to prefer `UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom` instead.