# Swift version of Objective C Macro : IS_IPHONE5

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I need swift version of below Obj.C Macro

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

#define IS_IPHONE5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
```

Comment: The first part is a duplicate of *your own* question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541154/swift-version-of-objectivec-macro, and a search for IS_IPHONE5 shows several answers, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831850/how-should-i-replace-these-screen-size-and-device-type-macros-in-swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define these outside of a `class` tag

```
let IS_IPHONE = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
let IS_IPHONE5 = IS_IPHONE && UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568.0
```